# Information exposed by the wireless network card interface

Tags: ieee-802.11

In the 802.11 MAC, there are several parameters at the low-level such as the RTS/CTS threshold, Binary Backoff timers and NAV (Network Allocation Vector) timers to name a few.

Is it possible for an application to obtain information about these parameters? In other words, can channel status information be accessed by higher layers? For a specified chipset, how can one determine what information is exposed by the network card?

Comment: This is more a programming and API question. I think it might be better suited at [so].